# Get installed packages from RPM DB, BerkeleyDB

Tags: rpm, berkeley-db

I'm trying to get installed packages from some Docker image and need to do it without using/install `rpm`.
I know that `rpm` store it data in `/var/lib/rpm` inside Berkeley DB files.
When I read the `Packages` file I see binary data.
Is it possible to extract the data in human readable format (text) straight from the DB files?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this way lies madness.  That format *is* binary data, so at a minimum you'd have to write software that can dump it.  I know this risks being unhelpful, but you could have another container that has rpm installed...  `cp` the contents of /var/lib/rpm into it, then get your list with `docker exec -it /usr/bin/rpm -qa`.

Comment: There are well defined python bindings available; IIRC a lot or all of `yum` is python-based.